# linux huge page usage

Tags: linux

What are the disadvantages of using Linux (SUSE Linux 10 SP2 64-bit Itanium) huge pages on a server where only Oracle DB is running? There are no other applications on that server. Are there any issues one should be aware of?

Answer (score 2):

Huge pages are unswappable - but if your system is dedicated to running a database that shouldn't be an issue. Just size the amount of memory allocated to the database appropriately.

We run huge pages on all our production databases, it gave a small (~5% or so) speed up when we benchmarked it.

Remember to increase the mlock ulimit, setup `/proc/sys/kernel/{shmmax,shmall}`, and `/proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages`.

LWN did an indepth series on huge pages recently, it's worth reading - [here's](http://lwn.net/Articles/374424/) part 1. Some of the later parts go into the sysadmin aspects of huge pages.

Answer (score -1):

Larger pages can lead to memory fragmentation and large pages are more difficult to swap on the disk. There was an [excellent read about hugepages](http://lwn.net/Articles/359158/) on lwn.net back in 2009, I recommend you to take a look at it.

Comment: That article refers to the WIP transparent hugepage patch - it's not in any shipping Linux distros yet AFAIK. Current huge pages are completely non swappable.